# How to query with country name in overpass

Tags: python, openstreetmap, overpass-api

i am trying to query all the branchs of deutsche bank in germany.
please let me know why the below code does not return any results

**code**:

```
area["place"="country"]["name:de"="Deutschland"]->.s;
(
  node.s
  ["amenity"="bank"]
  ["brand"="Deutsche Bank"]
  ["atm"="yes"]
  ["addr:city"="Potsdam"];
);
  out count;
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things going on here:

1. place=country only applies to nodes (see [OSM tag documentation](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:place%3Dcountry)), so it cannot be used to define an area.
2. Each statement in your union still needs to be terminated with the search area and semicolon (like [this](https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/14vH)).
3. Lastly, be aware that (1) amenity=bank could potentially be applied to ways and relations in OSM while your current query only returns nodes and (2) that [count](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#out) does not output geographic data, so nothing will show up in the map window if you're using Overpass Turbo.